# how install Svelte framewoek with Rails 6+ and Sprocket (no webpack)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svelte, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I have a Rails 6 app and I want use Svelte on client side only

I have nodeJS, NPM and Yarn installed.

Now, how can I install Svelte to this app **without webpack**, only using sprocket ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jsbundling by adding the gem and then you have your choice of esbuild, rollup, or webpacker.

This article summarizes it well: https://anonoz.github.io/tech/2021/12/11/rails-tailwindcss-svelte.html

Another resource for jsbundling: https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails

The other option would be start with Rails 7 and declare esbuild from the beginning. Then you can just use Yarn to add Svelte to the project.

Comment: how install with yarn? it's npm on official site. I use guard to reload js or sass file on save and load it in page without reload, how can I autobuild .svelte to .js with guard ?
I don't know what is "esbuild"

Comment: Look at the first link I sent. It explains the process really well. Esbuild allows you to transpile JS without the need of webpacker, increasing the speed and performance of the app. You can add it through the jsbundling gem. Then follow the instructions on adding Svelte through Yarn.

Comment: I d'ont have rails 7 or esbuild...

I just need preprocessor .svelte to .js in my /app/assets/ and it's ok, so how watch save on .svelte and build file when change occure and define path for out code? (and desabled minimification for dev env it's better)